Good way to repair door with snap in style hinges
I have a cabinet door that hinge location is blown out. There are several methods for when the hinges are screwed to the cabinet door but I have not seen any methods for the Blum push in style hinges that I can find.
I previouly epoxied the holes and drilled out and it lasted about a year. Any reliable method is appreciated.


I ended up slathering in epoxy and made sure the epoxy didn't make contact with moving parts. This hopefully last a few years until a kitchen facelift.

I have had success with drilling and glueing in dowels and converting the hinge to screws.

As offered by Solar Mike, gluing in dowels is the best, ( least obtrusive) solution.
If that doesn't work there are repair plates available. The screw stanchions on the hinge can be cut off and holes drilled for the screws. Or you can purchase new screws.

They are both good if you are converting to screws, which is what I am trying to avoid, but may happen to do it it fails again.. I was able to expand out the latching mechanism and filled the bigger hole a little as was too deep for the the cupboard side hinge body and would cause pivoting on the clamp points and wear the wood/epoxy. Feels solid now.
